# Why are categories not called monoids (and why are monoids not called... mons?)

Tags: category-theory, monoid, groupoids

If groupoids are "indexed groups", wouldn't that same naming scheme imply that categories should be called "monoidoids", or more sensibly, why aren't categories called "monoids" and monoids called... "mon"s? "mono"s?

Comment: Mathematical terminology is seldom particularly logical.  Are you asking about the historical origins of this terminology?

Comment: @EricWofsey I guess a more causally sequentialized version of this question would be, why the "groupoid" name  is used in this way, inconsistently with "monoid".

Comment: Actually, does the name "monoid" even make sense before the category theoretical formulation? What is "one" ("mono") in a monoid in its algebraic formulation?

Comment: I agree with you that this would make more sense and match more closely with the fact that categories are basically "multi-sorted monoids", and be more consistent with what happens for groups and groupoids, which sounds much nicer. But the convention everyone got used to are not these ones. Probably if we were to name these notions now we would chose something in the flavour that you suggested. At the time they were named though, people did not have the same understanding of it as we do now

Comment: @ThibautBenjamin: so what about monoids is [*mono*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) in a non-categorical understanding? What I mean is, in a CT understanding of a monoid, there is a single object, so *mono*'s meaning of *only*, *unique* readily applies, but the name comes from a simple algebraic formulation, and I'm not seeing anything *mono* in that.

Comment: I do not know where the "mono" part comes from in monoid. But you can check the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156952/why-the-terminology-monoid/167900

Comment: A monoid has an identity; if there is an identity element, then it is unique. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mono-

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that groupoids were invented (or at least, named) *before* categories, and monoids slightly *after*.